# How to download and install MATLAB in Ubuntu with no GUI?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, path, matlab

I am working inside a docker container, and the only interface I have is the terminal.

I used `pip install matlab` and it does install the version 0.1, but when I write `matlab --version`, the message is `bash: matlab: command not found`. Even after adding its location to the PATH with the following comand I could not "find" the matlab command.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages:$PATH
```

Other than that, the error in my code when I try to run it is the following:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 516, in run
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop -r "try, main_READ_EDR, catch e, disp(getReport(e)), exit(1), end, exit(0);"' returned non-zero exit status 127.
```

And it is caused by this code:

```
run_matlab = 'matlab -nodisplay -nojvm -nosplash -nodesktop -r "try, main_READ_EDR, catch e, disp(getReport(e)), exit(1), end, exit(0);"'
    subprocess.run(run_matlab, shell=True, check=True)
```

So I'm trying to install MATLAB only through the terminal.

I have downloaded the zip using:

```
curl "https://esd.mathworks.com/R2022a/R2022a/installers/web/matlab_R2022a_glnxa64.zip?__gda__=1655716550_75cf1474d9abbfbb20d5e932ecba159e&dl_id=FC8e2LW2&ext=.zip" -o matlab_R2022a_glnxa64.zip
```

Then, I'm following this tutorial:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZNHJkCo5sOc&t=427s
```

Other than not being able to download `xhost`, when using `sudo ./install` inside the installer folder gives an error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'framework::window::DisplayError'
  what():  No display available.
Aborted
```